# How to log a method in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, logging

I am trying to see a log of my publishProgress() call in the Asyncktask class below. To see if it actually is calculating anything while it progresses. As it stands I have a progress dialogue that doesn't update.

```
 public String strAttachedFile = "";
 public float nTotalSize;
 public float nUploadSize;
public void Send(){

        new Loadvid().execute(); // our call for asynctask
    }

public class Loadvid extends AsyncTask <String,Integer,String>{

            protected void onPreExecute(){
            m_vwProgress.setMax((int)nTotalSize);
            m_vwProgress.setMessage("Uploading, Please wait...");
            m_vwProgress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
                m_vwProgress.show();
            }
        }

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


            boolean m_bSuccess = true; 
            try
            {

                MultipartEntity me = new MultipartEntity();

                File pFp = new File(strAttachedFile);
                me.addPart("videoFile", new FileBody(pFp, "video/3gpp"));
                httppost.setEntity(me);
                // get the total size of the file
                nTotalSize = pFp.length();

                HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(httppost);  
                HttpEntity resEntity = responsePOST.getEntity(); 

                InputStream inputstream = resEntity.getContent();
                StringBuilder stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();
                byte data [] = new byte[512]; 

                while ((len = inputstream.read(data))>0 )
                {
                    StringBuilder result= stringbuilder.append(new String(data, 0, len)); 
                     String s = String.valueOf(result);
                     nUploadSize += len;
                     publishProgress((float)(nTotalSize/nUploadSize));
                      String myString1 = Float.toString((int)nUploadSize);
                     String myString2 = Float.toString((int) nTotalSize);

                     Log.i("Upload SIZEEEEEEEE", myString1);
                     Log.i("Total SIZEEEEEEEE", myString2);

                }
                inputstream.close();

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                m_bSuccess = false; 
            }

            if(m_bSuccess){
                return "success";//Success

            }

            return null;//failed
        }

protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {

            if(m_vwProgress !=null){

                m_vwProgress.setProgress(values[0]);
                }
        }


        protected void onPostExecute(String result){

            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result==null){
                // failed
                if(m_vwProgress !=null)
                    m_vwProgress.dismiss();

                return;
            }
            else
            {
                //success
                if(m_vwProgress !=null)
                    m_vwProgress.dismiss();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just like you are doing: call `Log.<level>(tag, message);`. The message should then show up in the `LogCat` window. If it doesn't you are either not getting to that method call or the `message`-parameter is empty.

Comment: @Jave if i add this:  Log.i("Show progresssss", "publishProgress()");
 It gives me an error and won't run. Thats why i am trying to figure out how to show the publishProgress(). Thansk for your answer by the way

Answer (score 0):

Try to match the variable types between `publishProgress` & `onProgressUpdate` parameters

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(float... values)
```

or

```
publishProgress((Integer)(nTotalSize/nUploadSize)*100);
```

Comment: This assumes one of the divisor and dividend are floats. If they're both integers then this will still calculate 0. A float cast needs to be on one of the numbers.

Comment: From their names, they are file sizes, so they are more than 1, so this will not calculate as zero.

Comment: What I am trying to do is upload a video file. For a log of the nTotalsize number its usually in 100000 bytes, the upload size however is normally 120. This is trying to upload a 1 second video. Im still not getting any progress to show. By the way I'm fairly new at android dev. Thanks

Comment: I mean if they are both integers then this will still be integer division, which will return an integer. Also the variables in the division should be the other way around.

Comment: @user875139 I see, so you need the progress to decrease. Try using m_vwProgress.setMax(nTotalSize) before m_vwProgress.incrementProgressBy(values[0]);

Comment: @midoalageb I tried that but it still doesn't work and on my update bar it shows 100, instead of nTotalSize. I am going to edit my question and put what I actually have as a code so you can perhaps see the whole picture

Comment: I think you should still match the variables. Either use publishProgress((Integer)(nTotalSize/nUploadSize)); or use protected void onProgressUpdate(float... values)

Comment: @midoalageb I have changed everything to a float including onProgressUpdate(float...values). the problem is within that method I cannot cast from float to int for m_vwProgress.setProgress((int)values[0]));

Comment: Try Integer val=Integer.ValueOf(values[0]); then m_vwProgress.setProgress(val);