# boolean in a conditional statement on android?

Tags: java, android, file-upload, conditional-statements, boolean

I am trying to  make a boolean which says "is_uploaded = true" as soon as a video finishes uploading. Such as:

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result)
 {


    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if(result==null)
    {

      if(dialog != null)
      dialog.dismiss();
      Toast...failed
    }
      else
       {
        //success
        if(dialog !=null)
        dialog.dismiss();
        boolean IS_UPLOADED = true
       }
 }
```

I am then trying to use this boolean earlier in the class to tell the user the file has uploaded. Especially if the user is in tries to send the video immediately again or is still in the same class of the app. Such as:

```
    if (IS_UPLOADED==false)
     { 
      new Loadvid().execute(null,null,null);
     }
        else
         {
          Toast.makeText(send.this, "This Video already  Uploaded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

         }
```

The problem is, I know you cant use a variable before it is created. This is the quickest method i could think of without the need of creating a database. Any suggestions would help, Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your code so it's indented more sensibly. It's horrible to read at the moment. (At the same time, think about giving the IS_UPLOADED variable a more conventional name, and performing a rather more appropriate comparison...)

Comment: I have submitted a tidier version however I need to wait for a moderator to publish as I am not all powerful yet...

Comment: Please  share full Asyctask class code in your post..

Comment: Something isn't adding up. The first IS_UPLOADED is scoped inside the onPostExecute method and is a boolean, is the second use in the same method? It looks like a different variable, because you're comparing it as a string (unless you mean == false)...

Comment: See scope questions in my answer

Comment: @imrankhan here is a link to full async http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602336/how-to-log-a-method-in-android

Answer (score 1):

Your code is formatted so bad it's hard to tell what's up, but the scope of your variable IS_UPLOADED is only inside the braces `{}`.

Additionally, to test IS_UPLOADED you must use == (not =) and the value to test will be true or false, not "true" or "false"

[edit]
How can you be `trying to use this boolean earlier in the class`?  the IS_UPLOADED in the first code segment is not in scope in the second code segment - how many IS_UPLOADED's have you defined?
[/edit]

Comment: thats part of the reason i was asking if you can do this? I have only defined 1 IS_UPLOADED  boolean which is at the bottom. I am trying to get a way to reference that boolean by calling it at the top scope. As I said I am trying to avoid using a database and calling a row "IS_UPloaded" and such...

Comment: Please post the entire onPostExecute method - without that, I can't figure out which pieces go where.....